# Получение пользовательского ввода, путем прокрутки listView

Tags: java, android, listview

1. Подскажите какой метод лучше для получения значения с listView (юзер не вводит значение, а выбирает из доступных значений, путем прокрутки listView). Получим строчное значение, переведем его в float, затем нужно записать его в переменную.
2. Если юзер использует первый listView, то считаем по одной формуле, а если второй, то по другой формуле, понимаю, что это делается с помощью if()/else, но как написать в скобках:
   if (юзер прокрутил первый listView) { считаем так } else { считаем так };

Comment: UPD. Подскажите, как определить какой именно listView прокручивается пользователем.
Например, if ("прокручиваемыйListView" == listView_1) { ... };

Comment: AdapterView<?> parent - это и есть ListView, можно сравнивать напрямую ссылки if( parent == listView_1) или как уже писал через id if( parent.getId() ==  R.id.list_view_1) (см.ниже)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ставим "слушатель". Вариант 1 раздельные на 2 списка, вариант 2 общий, определяем через parent.getId() == R.id.list_view_1 и т.п.

```
listView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              String data = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
              try{
                  float number = Float.valueOf( data );
              }catch( Exception e ){
              };

            }
        });
```